# Fake Incoming Call Android

Tags: android, adb

How can I fake an incoming call inside the android emulator?

The following lets me make a call but I'd like to force the emulator to receive
a call, preferably from a number I've selected.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL tel:1112223333
```

So, the direct opposite of the command above.

Comment: I was going to comment that OP should accept an answer, but I noticed that he was last seen at the time he posted the question, not one minute later. That means he never even saw the answers.. quite a sad story

Answer (score 61):

You can use DDMS in Eclipse, Android Device Monitor in Android Studio or run command lines on terminal

**Using DDMS:**

- Open DDMS/ADM

  - in Eclipse: Window > Open Perspective > DDMS
  - in Android Studio: Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor
- Enter the fake incomming phone number
- Choose "Voice"
- Press call

[image]

After that, you will see the emulator receive this phone call as follows 

[image]

**Using command lines**

> $ telnet localhost 5554 
>   $ gsm call 123456789

Note: 5554: console port number for emulator instance 
12345678: incoming phone number

Comment: My "Emulator Control" is disabled! I can't modify any checkbox or input field. Why?

Comment: Device monitor is deprecated and removed after Android studio 3.2 https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor

Comment: Using latest version of Android Studio, I do not have the option: Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor
Is there any new way on latest version?

Answer (score 28):

Actually in android Studio 2.1 Its easy!

[image]

[image]

Comment: but what about real device connected through usb-adb?

Answer (score 16):

You can do this with Putty. Download and install Putty http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

**Step 1**: 
    Run Putty

**Step 2**: In the address box put 127.0.0.1

In the port box put the port number your emulator is running on. It's in the top left corner of the emulator window (usually 5554). Make sure type is set to 'telnet'. Click 'Open'

**Step 3**: 
    A terminal will open. Type:

```
gsm call <the number you want the phone to see>
```

Press enter and you're done.

EDIT: 
You can also send fake sms:

```
sms send <the number you want the phone to see> <the message>
```

Comment: For some reason on my computer, the gsm command doesn't get recognized the first time I type it in. Typing it the second time, it works fine. Not sure why. Just wanted to let you guys know.

Answer (score 6):

if you are using eclipse then you can simply do this using emulator control 
for this click on window in eclipse menu then show view now click on other
a small window will open select android and then emulator control

use it for making call in emulator

Comment: If view is greyed out then make sure you also open the device view and click on your emulator.

Answer (score 4):

Another option for testing the same behavior is to use a real phone and Google's two step authorization settings to generate calls (see image).

[image: voice call]

Comment: attached image does not seen

Comment: This method doesn't seem like the right way to do it

Answer (score 2):

There are three options which i recently checked to get simulated call on a Android emulated device (AVD).

**option 1:**

Go to emulated device "more" option as shown below and hit on "Call device" to get a call from number mentioned.

[image]

**option 2:**

Using emulated device UI check the phone number by going to Settings--> System --> About emulated device as shown below. Call to this number from the other device.

[image]

**option 3:**

Launch Android device monitor (e.g. on windows "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools" launch monitor), set your own incoming number and call as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Shell script **incoming_call.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
expect << EOF
spawn telnet localhost 5554
expect -re ".*>"
send "gsm call $1\r"
expect -re ".*>"
send "exit\r"
EOF
```

Usage:

```
incoming_call.sh +55555555555
```

Comment: system/bin/sh expect not found

Comment: maybe you are Windows user

Answer (score 1):

Handy one-liner on unix-like systems using telnet and netcat:

```
 $ echo "gsm call 123456789" | nc -v  localhost 5554
```

Comment: @DovidBender I was using the Android studio emulator. It uses the [5554 port by default](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking).

Answer (score 1):

on a real device

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:+CCXXXXXXXXXX
```

CC is country code , XX is phone number

Comment: This is placing a call, not for an incoming call.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by connecting to your emulator via telnet.
Open **Command Prompt** and enter

```
telnet localhost <console-port>
```

You can find your `<console-port>` on the title bar of the emulator.
[image]

According to the above instance my `<console-port>` is 5554.

After connecting to the emulator via telnet, enter

```
gsm call <telephone-number>
```