# How to turn off my media service for an incoming call? My AudioManager is not working

Tags: android, sdk, media-player, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to setup my audio playing app to stop playback if there is an interruption.  I followed directions in Android SDK Developer notes about setting up an AudioFocusHelper like so:

```
public class AudioFocusHelper  implements AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {
    AudioManager mAudioManager;  
    Media_Service mService;
    Context mContext;
    public AudioFocusHelper(Context ctx, Media_Service svc) {  
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);        
        mService = svc;    
        }    

    public boolean requestFocus() {        
        return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED ==            
                mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,            
                        AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);    
        }    

    public boolean abandonFocus() {        
        return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED ==            
                mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);    
        }    

    @Override    
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {        
        // let your service know about the focus change    
        mService.AudioFocus(focusChange);
    }
}
```

and I have my audio player running in a service as they suggest.  I have this method in my audio service to respond to Audio Focus changes to pause the playback but its not working -- I don't know how to test this in the vm debugger so I can't really see what is happening on an incoming call.  It doesn't appear to get called since I told it to popup toasts:

```
public void AudioFocus(int focusChange) {
    switch (focusChange) {        
    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:            // resume playback           
        if (mMediaPlayer == null) 
            initMediaPlayer();            
        else if (!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) 
            mMediaPlayer.start();            
        //mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);            
        break;        
    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:            // Lost focus for an unbounded amount of time: stop playback and release media player            
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Playback interrupted by focus loss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mMediaPlayer.stop();     
        }
        mMediaPlayer.release();            
        mMediaPlayer = null;            
        break;        
    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:            // Lost focus for a short time, but we have to stop           
        // playback. We don't release the media player because playback            
        // is likely to resume            
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Playback paused by focus loss (transient)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mMediaPlayer.pause();      
        }
        break;        
    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:            // Lost focus for a short time, but it's ok to keep playing            
        // at an attenuated level            
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())  {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Playback paused by focus loss (duck)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mMediaPlayer.pause();            
            //mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f); 
        }
        break;    
    }   
}
```

I can post more of the code if necessary, it seems like I'm posting a lot of code already and I don't want to post an excessive amount.  It looks to me like my onAudioFocusChange just isn't getting called.  I am running this on Android 2.2 (minSDK 8) since these feature is not supported before 2.2.  Searched hi and low for tips and I find very little about this topic at all so I'm hoping somebody out there can give me some clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same issue, remember you need to call the requestFocus() method when you start playback and abandonFocus() when you are done.

Comment: Thanks, what an idiot I am, that's exactly what happened.  Once I added requestFocus() then my onAudioFocusChange() method started getting called as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help with generating incoming calls through DDMS: [Fake Incoming Call Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964703/fake-incoming-call-android)

Hopefully, you can debug your application with this.

Comment: Actually, turns out I could just make a fake call using the call button on the emulator -- that was an easy way to test on the debugger!