# is it possible to emulate incoming phone calls to a non mobile device

Tags: android, android-debug

If I use a real real device to test out my android programs, but the device is a tablet computer and not a phone in any way, can I still use the SDK to emulate incoming phone calls and SMS, and the device into receiving phone calls and sms? Or do I have to get a real phone device for this purpose?

Comment: What do you mean by **spoof**? The AVD has features to test calls. Check out the various function keys. See [Android Emulator
](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)

Comment: As I said, I am not talking about the emulator. It is possible for SDK  to make spoof calls to the emulator using DDMS (as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964703/fake-incoming-call-android). I just want to know if this is possible on a real hardware but which does not have phone capabilities, or do I need to have a real phone instead

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use Emulator to do this [Using the Emulator|Telephony Emulation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#telephony). The emulator is a part of android sdk and it is free to use.

I don't think a tablet without a hardware can do this. Or you may wait and watch if the others think differently.

Comment: I agree. I still don't understand the "spoof" part.

Comment: ok may be that wasn't the proper word. Call it "emulate" an incoming call