# Fake Incoming Call on an Android device

Tags: android, adb, telephony

Is there a way to fake calls for android devices that I have plugged in via usb? Some way to trigger a call using ADB? If so, how do I do it?

I feel like this might be a duplicate question but I can't find a SO question for it. [This is the closest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964703/fake-incoming-call-android), but it only relates to the emulator.

Here's some things I've tried. I would like to do the reverse of the following command:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL tel:1112223333
```

Just like the other guy said in the question I linked to above. Except I would like to do this on a device, instead of in the emulator. For the work that I am doing the emulator is not sufficient for testing phone calls, I can only run my tests on actual devices. Our "solution" doesn't have emulator support.

So normally I would telnet into the local host using the emulator's port but I can't do that, so can I telnet into a plugged in device? Is there a way for me to fake an incoming call on a plugged in device?

To explain why I would want to do this, I am making modifications to AOSP at this time. At the moment we have not modified the emulator to work with our changes, but we are making modifications to telephony. Eventually getting the emulator to work will be important but at this time it would be ideal if we could test telephony with fake calls using the devices we have access to.

It is entirely possible that this is not even possible but if someone has experience with this I would love to know. I feel like there should be some tests somewhere for faking phone calls on devices before they release a device to the public.

Comment: I'm REALLY not sure how I can display some "minimal understanding of the problem". I've looked through other questions and I see no way of doing this, but the emulator is capable of receiving fake calls via DDMS. I'm ASSUMING that the device also has this functionality, and I'm hoping someone else knows how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Telnet to your Android device

Alternatively to adb you can also use telnet to connect to the device. This allows you to simulate certain things, e.g. incoming call, change the network connectivity, set your current geocodes, etc. Use "telnet localhost 5554" to connect to your simulated device. To exit the console session, use the quit or exit command.

For example

```
# connects to device
telnet localhost 5554
# set the power level
power status full
power status charging
# make a call to the device
gsm call 012041293123
# send a sms to the device
sms send 12345 Will be home soon
# set the geo location
geo fix 48 51
```