# Is it possible to simulate an incoming call to an android phone using adb?

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb

I have an android phone which is paired via bluetooth with a bluetooth headset device that I am programming for

To debug the headset code the smartphone with which the headset is paired should be receiving a call

Is it possible to simulate an incoming call to the android smartphone so that I do not have to make a real call to it? I do not need to write any code for the phone itself I just need it to be receiving a call so that the bluetooth headset thinks it is connected via HFP with the phone. If it is possible to use an audio file on the computer to simulate the audio in the call it would be even better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964703/fake-incoming-call-android

Comment: This is for the emulator, I need to do this in real hardware so that I don't have to pay for the calls I make during test